# Windows Credential Provider - destroyed before receiving credentials

Tags: c++, windows, com, winlogon, credential-providers

I'm writing a Windows credential provider and I'm relly struggling due to the lack of documentation on how the thing should work.

I started from the Windows SDK Example (`security/SampleCredentialProvider`) and modified it in order to receive the credentials from a SYSTEM service which acts as a server through a pipe.

The problem is: when the credential provider object (the one which implements `ICredentialProvider`) has [`GetCredentialCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/credentialprovider/nf-credentialprovider-icredentialprovider-getcredentialcount) called, it hasn't already received the credentials from the SYSTEM service through that pipe therefore I return a 0 credentials number (`*pdwCount = 0;`).

I'm not sure if this is the cause of the problem but the object **destructor is called soon thereafter**. That in turn destroys the pipe where I was waiting for the SYSTEM service credentials to be passed and nothing works.

My question is: why is the object which implements `ICredentialProvider` destroyed? How can I avoid its destruction in order to have the provider *wait* for credentials passed through the pipe and then notify LogonUI that we have new credentials?

I'm attaching some events taken from the Windows Event Viewer regarding my credential provider module:

```
- Credential provider object is created
- SetUsageScenario is called, only CPUS_LOGON is supported
- Advise is called, pcpe parameter is saved and AddRef'd
- GetCredentialCount, 0 is returned (no credential received yet)
- UnAdvise is called (this is unexpected, does this mean I can no longer pass credentials? Why is this called?)
- pipe to receive credentials is created
- Credential provider object's destructor is called -> pipe is destroyed and everything terminates
```

Comment: Have you tried returning `1`?

Comment: @Fozi in that case LogonUI will afterwards call `GetCredentialAt` and ask for the credential I lied I had. At that point I have no credential (not received from the pipe yet) and I can't make it up. I need to keep the pipe thread open to get the credentials from the SYSTEM service but LogonUI keeps shutting down my credential provider (along with my pipe thread).

Comment: *Windows:* Hello, `ICredentialProvider` #5, I'm building the UI. How many fields do you have? *`ICredentialProvider`#5:* Zero. *Windows:* KTHXBAI. ;)

Comment: @Fozi I don't understand.. we're talking about the provider::GetCredentialsCount right? What does it have to do with UI fields here? My reasoning was: 'I'll return 0 if my pipe in another thread hasn't returned me any credential yet, I'll return 1 if it has'. Does it make any sense?

Comment: @Fozi plus there is absolutely no reason why a credential provider should be destroyed if it has 0 UI fields. No UI doesn't mean the provider can be unloaded (there's no mention of that in any documentation)

Comment: https://github.com/oVirt/ovirt-guest-agent/blob/master/windows-credprov/OVirtProvider.cpp#L174 -> exactly as I'm trying to do right now.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue: I'm stuck at Ctrl+Alt+Del screen and the credential provider log I was looking at was RDP's one (I was using it to log in and debug the issue).